# Excel Space cannot be seen

Tags: excel

I copied some names from translate.google.com. Then I pasted it on excel (each name in a column).

Now when I want to split it to keep the first name only, it does not work. It seems like excel can't see the space anymore.

I used this code:

```
=LEFT(R2;SEARCH(" ";R2;1))
```

Comment: Have you tried using `MID` to capture one of the spaces and then applying `CODE` to it to see what the ASCII code is?  It may not be the kind of whitespace you are expecting.

Comment: You have semi-colons in your code - I assume you have commas in your real code? Also, you need `=LEFT(R2,SEARCH(" ",R2,1)-1)` (note the minus one).

Comment: "it does not work"  What does this mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use commas (,) to separate your variables in the formula, so like this:

```
=LEFT(R2,SEARCH(" ",R2,1))
```

Does that help?

If not, please also post the contents of cell R2.

Comment: This is not the issue. In some locales (e.g. version of Excel for some European countries), semicolons are required instead of commas.

Comment: When giving a -1 to someone, it would be nice to explain why.